# What image filter is used in max pooling in image processing

Tags: conv-neural-network, image-processing, convolution, pooling

I am curious to know which filter is used in to do max pooling? I am aware that it is a Deconvolution layer.

As it takes the maximum value across all pixels - would it use an nonlinear area filter? As it modifies pixels taking into account neighbourhood pixels, and the pixels are defined by other functions aka the max

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. A pooling layer averages or takes the max of a patch of activations from the feature map produced by a convolutional layer. The purpose of pooling layers isn't to introduce nonlinearity but rather to reduce computational complexity and introduce translational invariance.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. To put it more simply, I am wondering what type of image filter does the max pooling involve - point filter or area filter? and whether it is linear or non linear. Not sure if that is clearer